# Argentinian employee working remotely from the US

Tags: working-abroad

I’m an Argentinian citizen, married to a US citizen. I am working for an American company but I was hired in Argentina. I used to come to the US often for business and met my now husband. Already started the process for the residence, but my employer  here and in Argentina say that I can’t continue working legally like this(getting paid in Argentinian pesos as I’m an Argentinian employee but working from the USA). 
Is this really like that? I don’t see where the illegality comes from.

Thank you !

Comment: What visa are you on? Unless you have work authorization or a work visa, I think your company is correct.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. For now I have my regular Visa B2(I think) and  still awaiting for the government authorization.  So you think that even if I’m hired in Arg. and getting paid in pesos I can’t keep doing it .